# How to make an exact copy of a directory to an another partition?

Tags: ntfs, acl, hardlink, directory-junction

I have a 20Gb folder on an ntfs drive. How can I make an exact of only that folder to an another ntfs volume?

By exact, I mean, copy pemissions; keep directories hard links *(if any)*; and keep alternate data streams. Junctions should be copied as junctions and symbolic links as symbolic links.
It doesn't have to be done with windows. Other os like freebsd can be used. However, in windows it needs to works from winre.

Things like xcopy or robocopy were no help. I heard far manager can retain hard links, but I'm unsure.

A graphical solution would be a +

Answer (score 2):

Use `ln` from Hermann Schinagl you can find it [here](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/ln/ln.html). Free for personal use and some work use, check the [licence](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/ln/license.txt). It does everything you need and is a Windows command line tool.

Comment: ln doesn’t seems to deal with permissions.

Comment: Yes it does with `--backup`

Comment: It doesn't seems to deal with alternate data streams.

Comment: Yes it does, and by default `The --noads option tells ln.exe not to copy Alternative Data Streams` RTFM

Comment: I forgot it had to works in winre. and it doesn’t.